# Passing parameters through HTML in .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in a .cshtml file:

```
var peopleList = $('#PeopleListTable').dataTable({
                    // not relevant
                    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                        var documentiddata = oObj.aData[0];
                        var notesdata = (oObj.aData[2]);
                        //alert(notesdata);

                        if (notesdata != null) {
                            var image = "images/AR/Check-on.png";                                                         
                            // return '<a href="#"  id="' + notesdata + '" onclick="return ShowNotes(this);">' + '<img  src="' + image + '" />' + '</a>';
                            return '<p><a onmouseout="return hideNotePopup();" onmouseover="return showNotePopup(notesdata, event);" href="javascript:void(0);" id="' + documentiddata + '">' + '<img  src="' + image + '" />' + '</a></p>'
                        } else {
                            return '<a href="#" id="' + documentiddata + '"> ' + '<img src="images/AR/Check-off.png" />' + '</a>';
                        }                         
                    }
                    },
                { "sName": "OfficerName", sType: "string", sWidth: "12%" },
                 { "sName": "CreateDate", sType: "string", sWidth: "15%" },
                 { "sName": "FinalizedDate", sType: "string", sWidth: "15%" },
                 { "sName": "TransferDate", sType: "string", sWidth: "15%" },
                 { "sName": "AgencyOri", sType: "string", sWidth: "10%" }
            ]
        });
```

Then this code in JavaScript:

```
function showNotePopup(notesdata, e) {
        $("#NoteDialog").dialog('close');
        $("#NoteDialog").removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-closethick");
        $("#NoteDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            position: [e.pageX, e.pageY-190]
        });
        $("#NoteDialog").dialog('open');
        document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = notesdata;
    }
```

The goal of this code is to hover over the note image in a data table, then have a popup show the contents of the note. Where I have `alert(notesdata)`, the note is shown properly. But when I hover over the image and examine the console, it says that `notesdata` isn't defined in the `showNotePopup()` call. I tried passing `this` and `oObj` as well, to no avail. How can I get `notesdata` from inside the cshtml to the javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `notesdata` exists only on the context of function `fnRender`. The event `onmouseover` is executed on a different context so the variable is out of scope. You need to change

```
onmouseover="return showNotePopup(notesdata, event);"
```

by

```
onmouseover="return showNotePopup(&quot;' + notesdata + '&quot;, event);"
```

Comment: +1. Note that `eval` in all its forms is generally considered bad practice... Unfortunately OP is constructing html with string concatenation instead of using some template engine or creating elements with jQuery - so this answer (minus script injection issues if `notesdata` comes from user) is ok approach.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi this is causing a syntax error whereas previously there wasn't one. The dev tools tells me there's an unexpected token }. Any reason that might be? Also, I swapped the order of the single and double quotes in your answer because the whole return statement is enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @aquemini: sorry, I made a mistake on quoting. Please try with the edited version